# Javascript and mySQL dateTime stamp difference

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime

I have a mySQL database in which I store the time in this format automatically:

```
2015-08-17 21:31:06
```

I am able to retrieve this time stamp from my database and bring it into javascript. I want to then get the current date time in javascript and determine how many days are between the current date time and the date time I pulled from the database.

I found this function when researching how to get the current date time in javascript:

```
Date();
```

But it seems to return the date in this format:

```
Tue Aug 18 2015 10:49:06 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

There has to be an easier way of doing this other than going character by character and picking it out from both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the difference directly in your query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(now(), myDateCol) FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build a new date in javascript by passing the data you receive from your backend as the first argument.
You have to make sure that the format is an accepted one. In your case we need to replace the space with a T. You may also be able to change the format from the back end.
Some good examples are available in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```
var d = new Date("2015-08-17T21:31:06");
console.log(d.getMonth());
```

To calculate the difference in days you could do something like this:

```
var now = new Date();
var then = new Date("2015-08-15T21:31:06");
console.log((now - then)/1000/60/60/24);
```

Comment: tracking, but whats the best way to determine days between both dates?

Comment: This answer has poor cross browser compatibility. It works fine in chrome but calling `new Date("2015-08-17 21:31:06").getTime()` in FF returns `NaN`. Per the docs you need to manually extract each parameter to pass to the date constructor.

Comment: good catch @JaredSmith based on what I could see in the MDN docs we need to have a T instead of a space between the date and time.

Comment: Also note that division in javascript does *not* return an integer like `Date.now()` does.

Comment: @JaredSmith I don't think we are expecting the division to return an integer.

Comment: *You* might not be, what about the OP? In many other languages integer division yields an integer.

Comment: Well you saved my life :) was having issues matching date in the pentaho data integration, just got the issue, needs to place T between the date and time in the string, you are the champ... :)

Answer (score 0):

the Date object has a function called getTime(), which will give you the current timestamp in milliseconds. You can then get the diff and convert to days by dividing by (1000 * 3600 * 24)
e.g.

```
var date1 = new Date()
var date2 = new Date()
var diffInMs = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()
var diffInDays = diffInMs/(1000*3600*24)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to provide more explanation and a full example with your answers. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.

Comment: @Madness: Thanks for your help. I have updated the comment with a code example.

Comment: Thanks so much @SouvikMitra!

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the other answer got it quite right:

```
var pieces = "2015-08-17 21:31:06".split(' ');
var date = pieces[0].split('-');
var time = pieces[1].split(':');

var yr = date[0], mon = date[1], day = date[2];
var hour = time[0], min = time[1], sec = time[2];
var dateObj = new Date(yr, mon, day, hr, min, sec);

//if you want the fractional part, omit the call to Math.floor()
var diff = Math.floor((Date.now() - dateObj.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Note that none of this deals with the timezone difference between the browser and whatever you have stored in the DB. Here's an offset example:

```
var tzOff = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000; //in ms
```